# grails validate method on domain object

Tags: grails, validation

I wrote a very simple test case and found that Grails does only a shallow validation when i call validate on a domain object. Is it possible for me to do a deep validation in grails? Can anybody help me?

```
class Person {
  Address address
}

class Address {
 String city
}
```

When i do new `Address().validate()` it returns false but when i do `new Person(address: new Address()).validate` it returns true.

Answer (score 7):

While "deep validation" currently isn't documented for the [`validate()`](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) and [`save()`](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) methods, it [will be in future](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4740) (the document states that the documentation has been missing, while being relevant for the complete 1.3.x tree). The documentation on these methods' `deepValidate` parameter then [will state](https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/69d3e3b43ff9599bd772):

> @deepValidate@ (optional) - Determines
>   whether associations of the domain
>   instance should also be validated,
>   i.e. whether validation cascades or
>   not. This is @true@ by default - set
>   to @false@ to disable cascading
>   validation.

Tests, however, show that "deep validation" is **not** performed in any of these cases:

- one-to-one associations
- one-to-many associations

  - associated objects assigned using the matching setter
  - associated objects assigned using the matching `addTo*(..)` method, e.g., `person.addToAddresses(..)`
- using both the `validate()` and `save()` methods,

  - and also, using both methods with an explicit `deepValidate: true` parameter

[Similar findings have been published at another place](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/no-validation-or-failOnError-for-cascades-td2122537.html), categorizing the "non-behavior" as a "known issue". My own, comprehensive, test cases can be [downloaded from here](http://rapidshare.com/files/431821513/deepValidateTests.zip).

The **solution**, finally, is to manually invoke validation on the child object:

```
class Person {
    Address primaryAddress
    static hasMany = [secondaryAddresses: Address]

    static constraints = { 
        primaryAddress validator: { 
            it?.validate()
        }
        secondaryAddresses validator: {
            it?.every { it?.validate() }
        }
    }
}
```